# search between dates how to show in jtable

Tags: java, netbeans

Here is code,  i am using 2 jdatechooser and i put the codes in a button. I am also not sure if the query is correct.

```
  private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try 
{ 

  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url="jdbc:sqlserver://USER-PC:1433;databaseName=tblgg";
        String userr="sa";
        String passs="1234";
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,userr,passs);

  java.util.Date first =  dt1.getDate();
    java.util.Date second = dt2.getDate();
   String sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_sale WHERE date between '"+ first+"'and 
    '"+second+"'";

 PreparedStatement pst= con.prepareStatement(sql);



   ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
 tblsale.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);  
} 
}
```

Okay i edit my code. xD now something is happening but nothing is showing up.

Comment: Never put any SQL into a GUI (see about MVC). Don't concatenate your query with the values then use a `PreparedStatement`... if you want to propose an SQL-Injection, at least do it using a `Statement`. Then, have you tried to populate a `JTable`, or to look how to do it?

Answer (score -2):

To correct your lack of prepared statement usage. Try this

Resuse your connection

```
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String url="jdbc:sqlserver://USER-PC:1433;databaseName=tblgg";
    String userr="sa";
    String passs="1234";
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,userr,passs);
    ResultSet result = null; 

    String sql2 =  "select\n" +
            "*\n" +
            "from student\n" +
            "where date(first) > ? and date(second) < ?";
    PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement( sql2, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY) ;
    ps1.setObject (1 , startDatePicker.getModel().getValue());
    ps1.setObject (2 , endDatePicker.getModel().getValue());


    result = ps1.executeQuery();
    // get number of rows
    result.last();
    numRows = result.getRow();
    result.first();
    //Get metadata object for result
    ResultSetMetaData meta = result.getMetaData();
    // create an arry of string for the colum names
    colNames = new String[meta.getColumnCount()];
    // store column names in the new col names array
    for( int i = 0; i< meta.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        //get column name
        colNames[i] = meta.getColumnLabel(i+1);

    }
    // create 2 d string array for table data
    tableData = new String [numRows][meta.getColumnCount()];
    // store columns in the data
    for ( int row = 0 ; row < numRows; row++)
    {

        for (int col = 0; col < meta.getColumnCount(); col++)
        {
            tableData[row][col]= result.getString(col + 1);

        }

        result.next();
    }


    // close statement
    ps1.close();
    connection.close();
    System.out.println("Data Table Loaded.");





}
```

To show the created result data set you use these lines

```
JTable table = new JTable(tableData,colNames);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Don't forget to add the scroll pane to your JPanel

```
panel.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: Using the metadata are complicated for someone that failed using a `PreparedStatement` ... and are unecessary for a specific query. Just use a mock table for your soluton with `Select A, B from myTable`... this would be cleaner, shorter, ..

Comment: mock table does not show up on a Java api search . Please explain the class mock table